# how to stop configuring network services

Tags: 12.04, networking

My computer upon start up taking about 5 minute during boot time configuring network and allowing 60 seconds to complete its task. how to stop these services. it starting this services every time upon start up. could me help me on above issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a know bug . Check out [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/856810) for more details about the bug.

There is a workaround for this issue. You may need to reinstall the network-manager and ligthdm . Please refer [this blog](http://www.totalcomputersusa.com/2011/10/ubuntu-11-10-booting-system-without-full-network-configuration/) for more details about this workaround